# What should I do about an error message I am getting when trying to build the Perl package for my Yocto distro?

Tags: yocto

I'm trying to build my [Yocto](https://www.yoctoproject.org/) Distro. (Based on Yocto 2.1/krogoth, My BUild Machine is an Ubuntu 16.04)

The package `perl` can not installed correctly. (I think it is the step `do_populate_sysroot`)

My error Messages:

> ```
> ERROR: Error executing a python function in /home/ubuntu/fsl-release-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/perl/perl_5.22.0.bb:
> ...
> Exception: CalledProcessError: Command 'cd /home/ubuntu/fsl-release-bsp/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/perl/5.22.0-r0/sysroot-destdir; find . -type d -print | tar -cf - -C /home/ubuntu/fsl-release-bsp/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/perl/5.22.0-r0/sysroot-destdir -p --files-from - --no-recursion | tar -xf - -C /home/ubuntu/fsl-release-bsp/build/tmp/sysroots/nuco-solo' returned non-zero exit status 2 with output tar: ./usr/lib/perl5: Cannot create symlink to 'perl': File exists
> tar: ./usr/lib/perl5: Cannot create symlink to 'perl': File exists
> tar: ./usr/lib/perl5: Cannot create symlink to 'perl': File exists
> tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
> ERROR: Function failed: sstate_task_postfunc
> ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/ubuntu/fsl-release-bsp/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/perl/5.22.0-r0/temp/log.do_populate_sysroot.10030
> ERROR: Task 2104 (/home/ubuntu/fsl-release-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/perl/perl_5.22.0.bb, do_populate_sysroot) failed with exit code '1'
> ```

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: You do not have a Perl problem. You seem to have decided it is better to post a question here than to read the actual message: "**Cannot create symlink to 'perl': File exists**" If you don't know what that means, you should learn the basics before attempting to program. Sometimes overriding the error using an option like `--force` or similar is the right thing to do. Sometimes it is not. You might want to try [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @SinanÜnür: It's a bit more complicated than that because the error comes from an automated build system trying to do its job. And the question really is why there is something in the sysroot that breaks the perl build. But I guess to answer that we need way more info about particular build setup.

Comment: delete the bspdir/tmp folder and bitbake again.